# Ionic Angular InAppBrowser Redirect Post

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, post, inappbrowser

I'm trying to redirect my app to 3DS for a payment method. The documentation says that:

> Get the action.url and the action.method from the /payments response.
>
> Redirect the shopper to the specified url using the HTTP POST, and
> include the contents of the data object in the request.

I got the URL, the method (POST) and the data body. Now I want to use the component `InAppBrowser` with this URL and POST data to open a new browser, but I can´t open correctly because I don't know how to use this component with a POST method.

I'm trying something like this:

```js
  let pageContent = '<form action="'+result.action.url+'" 
  method="'+result.action.method+'">' +
  '<input type="hidden" name="md" value="'+result.action.data.MD+'">' +
  '<input type="hidden" name="paReq" value="'+result.action.data.PaReq+'">' +
  '<input type="hidden" name="termUrl" value="'+result.action.data.TermUrl+'">' +
  '</form>'

  this.paymentGatewayObject.target = '_blank'
  this.paymentGatewayObject.options = `location=no,${this.platform.is('android') ? 
  ',hidden=yes' : ''}`

  const pageContentUrl = 'data:text/html;base64,' + btoa(pageContent)
  this.paymentGatewayObject.browser = this.InAppBrowser.create(pageContentUrl, 
  this.paymentGatewayObject.target, this.paymentGatewayObject.options)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to it using `webkit.messageHandlers.cordova_iab.postMessage(msgJson);`

You can check it the example here: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#example-1